# Can I unlock my phone with voice command?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command

I have a Samsung Galaxy Edge with Android 7.0. I want to rule my phone with my voice without touching it even if it's locked. I mean some basic functions, like unlocking the phone. So whenever I say my secret word my phone will unlock, or if I say "how many notifications" it will say "no new notifications" for example (without unlocking the phone). Is this possible or is there an app for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you search about it you may find application to do this, but i don't recommend it. because application like that need to turn on mic and process voices coming from it whole the time which shortens battery life.

Answer (score 1):

The unlocking can be done via Voice Access.  Refer to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234748/287958), at worst you may need to apply screen grid to input touches by screen coordinate.  As for the custom commands, I would go about that using a PC to deliver ADB commands, but the caveat obviously being the hardware dependency.  Actually, I've made similar scripts in the past except for RainMeter (one-click unlock, etc.).